# Can I bind two list of different type together?

Tags: c#, binding

I have a question about binding in the MVVM pattern. Let's say I have three classes MyView, MyViewModel and MyModel. Each one containing a static list:

```
static public List<Line> myViewList;             (for MyView)

static public List<MyViewModel> myViewModelList; (for MyViewModel)

static public List<MyModel> myModelList;         (for MyModel)
```

Is it possible to bind myViewList with myViewModelList and myViewModelList with myModelList ?

Comment: What do you mean by bind together? As bind two lists of different types on one ItemsSource? Or you have model object MyModel, that is represented in viewmodel as MyViewModel, that should be shown on view as Line?

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking if you can bind all three collections to an ItemsControls?

If so, yes - using [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx)

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Height="300" Width="200" Background="White">
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <CollectionContainer
        Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GreekGodsData}}" />
      <CollectionContainer
        Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GreekHeroesData}}" />
      <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

Above code from the MSDN documentation.

If you are asking whether you can bind the three static lists to eachother, then not directly. Bindings are meant to be used to bind your UI to their backing ViewModels, not to bind multiple static collections to eachother. That can be achieved by exposing yet another static collection with a getter something like this:

```
var col1 = new List<long>();
var col2 = new List<string>();

var totalCol = new List<object>();
totalCol.AddRange(col1);
totalCol.AddRange(col2);
```

Please note that there seems to be something fundamentally wrong with this design if you need a collection of all your views, viewmodels and models. Unless you have some scenario I don't understand, which is likely :)

Comment: I want to program a neural-network application like. So I want to add some shapes in my UI with specific signification behind it. The association process should give graphic information (like Lines in my view) as well as signification in my Model. That's why I want to bind at least my Model to my View to avoid direct reference.

Comment: It sounds like you should have a ViewModel holding your collections rather than a static list. In that ViewModel, you should expose properties matching what you want to show in your UI. So if all you want to show in your UI is Lines (and perhaps some circles to represent nodes), you should expose to the View a list of Lines and a list of Nodes, each having the data needed to display them. Any logic to make these lists should be contained in your ViewModel, or helper classes. In the ViewModel, there should be no need to data bind, as you can do whatever you want in code.